# c# implement IComparable interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, compare

how is the correct way to implement IComparable interface?
I have the following options:

```
public class Temperature : IComparable 
{
    // The temperature value
    protected double temperatureF;

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 1;

        Temperature otherTemperature = obj as Temperature;
        if (otherTemperature != null) 
            return this.temperatureF.CompareTo(otherTemperature.temperatureF);
        else
           throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Temperature");
    }
}
```

or

```
    public class Temperature : IComparable 
    {
        // The temperature value
        protected double temperatureF;

        public int CompareTo(object obj) 
        {
            if (obj == null) return 1;

            Temperature otherTemperature = obj as Temperature;
            try
            {
                return this.temperatureF.CompareTo(otherTemperature.temperatureF);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Temperature");
            }
        }
     }
```

Which one is correct way and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use exceptions as control flow mechanism in expected cases and because of that first option is better.

You should also consider implementing generic `IComparable<Temperature>` instead of non-generic `IComparable`:

```
public class Temperature : IComparable<Temperature>
{
    // The temperature value
    protected double temperatureF;

    public int CompareTo(Temperature otherTemperature) {
        if (otherTemperature == null) return 1;

        return this.temperatureF.CompareTo(otherTemperature.temperatureF);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are functionally correct, however, the first one I would consider 'more correct' than the other one.

The 'as' operator will return null if the object you are casting can not be cast to the target type. In the first example you are explicitly checking for this null value, and throwing in that case.

However in the second example you are allowing the code to crash (via a NullPointerException), and then catching that crash, only to throw an ArgumentException. This is a less favorable way of doing it for a number of reasons, but the largest one is the overhead of throwing an exception when you could easily just check for the null in the first place.